# Mark Out Multiple Delivery Zones on Google Map and Store in Database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-maps, postgis

**Background:**
I'm trying to use a Google Map as an interface to mark out multiple polygons, that can be stored in a Postgres Database.

The Database will then be queried with a geocoded Longitude Latitude Point to determine which of the Drawn Polygons encompass the point.

Using Python and Django.

**Question**
How do I configure the Google Map to allow a user to click around and specify multiple polygon areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to bind [event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) listeners to the [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) overlays.

[cool example, not exactly what you want here](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/mymapstoolbar.html).

[This example](http://zog.utc.edu/~ssmullen/maps/Ochs/index.html) has good basic events with Polygons. You can, instead of taking the event and making a info window, maybe take the polygon obj and add it to a object of clicked on Polygons to give to the server.

Then, you could use jquery or other and `ajax.post` the clicked-on data to a request handler. Use the Django models api to write to a `postgis`-enabled database using [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/).

Answer (score 1):

"Using Python and Django" only, you're not going to do this. Obviously you're going to need Javascript.

So you may as well dump Google Maps and use an open-source web mapping framework. OpenLayers has a well-defined Javascript API which will let you do exactly what you want. Examples in the OpenLayers docs show how.

You'll thank me later - specifically when Google come asking for a fee for their map tiles and you can't switch your Google Maps widget to OpenStreetMap or some other tile provider. This Actually Happens.

Comment: not actually to the specifics of the question but tempted to +1 because it's true what you say.